# Is lemon rind supposed to feel sticky when being grated?

Tags: baking

I was grating lemon rind for a lemon cake and noticed that it left a sort of sticky film on my hand. Is this normal or does it suggest that the lemon was not fresh?

My other question was about whether or not the lemon I used was spoiled, so perhaps the stickiness caused by the lemon was due to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Limonene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limonene), a major component of lemon oil, is not very water soluble, and will leave a sticky residue on your hands til you wash with soap and water.

Comment: Is this why lemons seem to feel stickier _after_ I use Veggie Wash on them?

Comment: Could be. Stores often spray fruit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_waxing with a solid wax. You take that barrier off and the liquid limonene can ooze right out onto your hands.